# PHP Warning: array_rand()

Tags: php

```
$d = 'Neo , Morpheus , Trinity , Cypher , Tank';
$input = array($d);

$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);
echo $input[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";
echo $input[$rand_keys[1]] . "\n";
```

> PHP Warning:  array_rand(): Second argument has to be between 1 and the number of elements in the array in /home/blogsvie/public_html/a.php on line 4

Comment: Whats your question? The error message is pretty clear. Your array has a single element.

Comment: Perhaps you mean to [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) that comma-delimited string?

Answer (score 0):

Your array has one element. A string containing   'Neo , Morpheus , Trinity , Cypher , Tank';

Create an array with more than one element, or explode that string into an array:

```
$d = 'Neo,Morpheus,Trinity,Cypher,Tank';
$input = explode(",",$d);
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);
echo $input[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";
echo $input[$rand_keys[1]] . "\n";
```